# Async Spark RDD Computation for variance/std/mean

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

In my code I have several computations that I perform on three different columns separately to compute the variance/std/mean etc.....  The problem is that this is running fairly long due to having to remap the values and then compute the variance for each column.

Is it possible to run all three of these statements async at the same time and retrieve the final value in the 3 variables specified below in the example?

```
final Double varSHOUR               = dataset.mapToDouble(new DoubleFunction<modelEhealth>() {
    @Override
    public double call(modelEhealth modelEhealth) throws Exception {
        return modelEhealth.getSHOUR();
    }
}).variance();
final Double varHOURLYFRAMESIN      = dataset.mapToDouble(new DoubleFunction<modelEhealth>() {
    @Override
    public double call(modelEhealth modelEhealth) throws Exception {
        return modelEhealth.getHOURLYFRAMESIN();
    }
}).variance();
final Double varHOURLYFRAMESOUT     = dataset.mapToDouble(new DoubleFunction<modelEhealth>() {
    @Override
    public double call(modelEhealth modelEhealth) throws Exception {
        return modelEhealth.getHOURLYFRAMESOUT();
    }
}).variance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to imitate Spark's implementation of `JavaDoubleRDD.variance()` using your `ModelHealth` class instead of Double. This isn't too hard, as you can use Spark's `StatCounter` to do the actual calculations, you'll just need 3 of them.

For the example, I'll use a simple `ModelHealth` with 3 `Double` fields v1, v2, v3:

```
static class ModelHealth {
    final Double v1;
    final Double v2;
    final Double v3;
}
```

Then:

```
JavaRDD<ModelHealth> dataset = // your data

// zero value - three empty StatCounters:
final Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> zeroValue = new Tuple3<>(new StatCounter(), new StatCounter(), new StatCounter());

// using `aggregate` to aggregate ModelHealth records into three StatCounters:
final Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> stats = dataset.aggregate(zeroValue, new Function2<Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter>, ModelHealth, Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter>>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> call(Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> stats, ModelHealth record) throws Exception {
        // merging record into tuple of StatCounters - each value  merged with corresponding counter
        stats._1().merge(record.v1);
        stats._2().merge(record.v2);
        stats._3().merge(record.v3);
        return stats;
    }
}, new Function2<Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter>, Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter>, Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter>>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> call(Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> v1, Tuple3<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter> v2) throws Exception {
        // merging tuples of StatCounters - each counter merged with corresponding one
        v1._1().merge(v2._1());
        v1._2().merge(v2._2());
        v1._3().merge(v2._3());
        return v1;
    }
});

Double v1_variance = stats._1().variance();
Double v2_variance = stats._2().variance();
Double v3_variance = stats._3().variance();
```

This gives the same result you had, but with a single aggregation over the dataset.

Comment: getting an error from the compiler on the 2nd part of your code when attempting to implement Function2 for the aggregation, must be declared abstract or implement an abstract method.

Comment: It compiles and runs successfully for me - did you change the "call" method signature? Make sure it matches super - input and return types should match the type definition.